# LaTeX referencing colorful numbering

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, color

I have some silly questions on LaTeX use:

1. In an article, how do I get colorful references like in the figure below?

   [image]
2. How do I reduce the built-in reference font size given below?

   [image]
3. How do I write multiple reference like fig(1) --> ref 5-8 ? If we write like as

   ```
    \cite{fahjhf1,hfafafa2, hafhad2, fhahgadfhd3}
   ```

then output comes [1,2,3,4], whereas I would like to get [1-4]

Comment: Can you post a Minimal Working Example? This will help people help you since with some set ups, at least some of this would be done more-or-less automagically and it is hard to say what you might tweak without knowing what you are using. For example, you'll get smaller font in your reference list than in its title with many styles because the title is typically a section or chapter heading and that is often set in a larger font size. Also, I'm not sure whether this should be three questions. If different people answer 1, 2 and 3 which answer will you accept?!

Comment: I think you want to pass style=numeric-comp as an option when loading biblatex to get the output you show for your third question. You may want hyperref for question 1. You might want something like \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small} to get the output in 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate a little on my comment above (which was not dissimilar to Werner's answer).

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

should get you blue citation links. (Default colour is green, I think.)

If you want the font used for references to be smaller than the reference size rather than making the reference size larger, renew the command \bibfont.

Passing style=numeric-comp compresses the references in the way you want but it seems that you need to pass the references as a comma separated list of keys. That is, it does not work with the multicitation commands of biblatex (at least, it didn't work for me).

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}

\begin{document}
\cite{aristotle:anima,aristotle:physics,aristotle:poetics}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives me:

[image]

when processed by biblatex -> biber -> biblatex -> biblatex.

Comment: Actually, maybe you wanted to make the header the size of the text in the references, in which case Werner's solution does that whereas mine will just create an even worse problem!

Answer (score 8):

1. Use the [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) with the `colorlinks` option.
2. Under [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) you can redefine the `bibliography` (default) heading using

   ```
   \defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
     \section*{\normalsize\bfseries #1}%
     \markboth{#1}{#1}}
   ```

   where you can update `\normalsize\bfseries` as expected. `\section*` doesn't end up in the ToC, which is why formatting it in this way should be sufficient.
3. Under [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) you can use the `sortsites` and `numeric-comp` options. This is similar to using the [`cite` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cite)'s (default) `compress` option.

Comment: Sortcites is superfluous. (I only know this because checked the description of numeric-comp for my comment above!)