# Change color of citation call-outs under hyperref

Tags: hyperref, citing

I have tried to find a solution to a problem that I am having regarding the color of the citation numbers. Below is the code that I have used for the links, but the citation numbers are still green. I've tried many options without any success and I wanted to ask if anyone can tell me what I am missing. I want them (the citation numbers) to be black (or another color, blue is another option).

**For the links in general:**

```
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\hypersetup{hidelinks,   
   backref=true,    
   pagebackref=true,    
   hyperindex=true,   
   breaklinks=true,
   colorlinks=true,
   urlcolor=blue,
   bookmarks=true,
   bookmarksopen=false,
   pdftitle={Title},
   pdfauthor={Author}}
```

and the outcome is in the screenshot

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried adding `citecolor = black` (or `citecolor = blue`) to the argument of `\hypersetup`?

Comment: Yeeey, it worked! How could I miss that? Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please keep in mind to add always a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` and not just a fragment. Have fun with latex.

Comment: Ok, I don't know how to do it so the admin(s) can do it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266694/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238098/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50747/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151604/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432609/35864. FWIW I don't think this question should be closed as off-topic. It has a useful answer (one that could be found by looking at the documentation, but useful nonetheless).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change reference colour to blue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238098/how-to-change-reference-colour-to-blue)